# How can I run python script without activating python environment everytime?

Tags: python

I have a python script whose dependencies are in the python environment. I want to convert python script to exe but before that i want to run python script without activating environment or automatically activate environment when the script starts. Is there any way i can achieve this so it will be easier for other people to use python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found the answer. This can be done by adding just two lines at the starting of your script.

For Python 3:
`activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'`
`exec(compile(open(activate_this, "rb").read(), activate_this, 'exec'), dict(__file__=activate_this))`

For Python 2:
`activate_this = '/path/to/env/bin/activate_this.py'`
`execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))`